# python index error: 2 lists that are inside a list

Tags: python, list

```
def main():
    L=[]
    list1=[5,1,3]
    list2=[4,6,2]
    L.append(list1)
    L.append(list2)
    f(L)

def f(L):
    for i in range(6)
         print L[i]



IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just appending the lists onto L so you get something like `[[5, 1, 3], [4, 6, 2]]`. You need to use `extend` like so:

```
L.extend(list1)
L.extend(list2)
print L      # [5, 1, 3, 4, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Appending two items to an empty list makes a 2-element list. Perhaps you wanted `L.extend()` instead?